# Multiple application header files included error in C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, integrity

I am doing a porting project implemented from INTEGRITY OS to UBUNTU. Facing compiler error as explained below. Even though not compiled in INTEGRITY OS, i think there is no errors there.
I got the root cause. I am expecting solution how i can achieve this.

`main.c`

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
#include "file3.h"
.
.
.
```

Inside all the files from
`file1.h` to `file3.h` below is there at the beginning of each file.

```
#ifdef INC_HEADER_FILE
    #error Multiple header files included.
#endif
#define INC_HEADER_FILE
.
.
.
```

Above throws error while compiling

```
In file included from ../main.c:
../file1.h: error: #error Multiple application header files included.
 #   error Multiple application header files included.
    ^~~~~
```

Same error is thrown for all the files for `file1.h` to `file3.h`

Comment: Show some [mre] in your question. Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), the C11 standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf), the documentation of [CPP](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/), the documentation of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Comment: "I got the root cause. I am expecting solution how i can achieve this." How you can achieve *what*, exactly? If all your header files use the same preprocessor variable as a guard, then it seems like you want to get an error on every include....

Comment: Read also the documentation of your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (perhaps [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/)...) and of your linker (probably in [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)...). You probably want to use an editor (such as [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)...) and a version control system (e.g. [git](https:////git-scm.com/)...) and of course you should **read their documentation**

Answer (score 3):

If all three (or however many there are) of those header files use the *same* symbol `INC_HEADER_FILE`, then you will only be allowed to include *one* of them.

That's because including (for example) `file1.h` will set that symbol, meaning that including the next header will complain because it's already defined.

The include guard symbol is usually specific to the header file itself, such as `INC_HEADER_1_FILE` but it's my no means necessary - I've seen this sort of thing done when you only want one variation of a header file.

An example of that is a system I worked on for LED display devices where each header had different dimensions. These were constructed from 8x8 units but different quantities across and down. Having the LED addressing map in a header file allowed for efficiencies that weren't available with dynamic configuration and the include guard made sure we didn't try to use more than one map.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the include guard for header1.h suggest:

```
#ifndef HEADER1_H
#define HEADER1_H
...
#endif
```

regarding the include guard for header2.h suggest:

```
#ifndef HEADER2_H
#define HEADER2_H
....
#endif
```

and similar for each header file.

The result is in any one compilation unit (source file.c) any specific header file can only be included once.